# Arabic Text Not Rendering Properly in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The problem is that the text in Arabic renders quite clearly at all locations but not renders properly in menus(Both top menu and main menu). The text looks like 2Ø®Ø§Ù†Ù‚Ø§Û there.

But at rest of the locations like page body and other places the text is rendered properly.

You can view the page at [khanqahnew.techmelo.com](http://www.khanqahnew.techmelo.com)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Your page's HTML tag has `lang="en-US"` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)
- Encoding of the PHP file(s), especially menus PHP file.
- Encoding of MySQL, or whatever database you have.